# Match all type of numbers

Tags: regex

I need regular expression which extracts all numbers with different delimiters (single whitespace, comma, dot). Each number can use none or all of them.

Example:

```
text: 'numbers:   3.14    2 544  345,345.55     506   test   120 100 100'

output: '3.14', '2 544', '345,345.55', '506', '120 100 100'
```

I created re: `\d+[(.|,|\s)\d+]+`, but it not works properly.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?  What is the delimeter between entries in your input data?

Comment: Try [`\d{1,3}(?:[, ]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/WhMNNS/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the numbers you need to extract are separated with 2 or more whitespaces, else it would be impossible to differentiate between the end of the previous number and the start of a new one.

If you need to extract the numbers in the formats as shown above, `XXX XXX.XXX` or `XXX,XXX,XXX.XX` or `XXX` or `XXX XXX XXX`, you may use

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:[, ]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhMNNS/2)

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:[, ]\d{3})*`  - 0+ sequences of a comma or space (`[, ]`) and 3 digits (`\d{3}`)
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a dot followed with 1+ digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

A less restrictive pattern would be the same as above, but with limiting quantifiers replaced with a `+`:

```
\b\d+(?:[, ]\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhMNNS/3)

It will also match numbers like `1234566` and `124354354.343344`.